# Hold the payment using paypal and Auto withdrawal Payment

Tags: node.js, angular8

1. I want to hold the payment for 48 hours is it possible by using paypal rest api?
2. I also want to auto withdraw the payment after 48 hours from business account to that particular merchant account Is it possible?.

I have used paypal-rest-sdk in my code and for backend purpose I have used node.js .